# ExtJS Why are multiple ajax requests waiting for eachother

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

I have a grid. For each item on the grid I have a menu on the left and its items change depending on the grid selection. Inside the `selection` event I have an `Ajax.request` that handles the rendering on its `success:`. The problem is that if I click on different rows really fast (or use the arrow keys to navigate quickly) the grid 'freezes' until the rendering of the request is finished, however it registers the different rows i've clicked and seems to be putting each consecutive request on a queue. If you check the network on the browser debugger it says that the request is pending which shouldn't happen since the call is async. Am I missing something? Is Ext handling Ajax differently?

Comment: You haven't posted any code, so it's not really possible to say. Ext doesn't have a "request queue", it will fire off the requests as soon as you make the call. You may be hitting a browser limitation with a number of concurrent requests, or have some other issue in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is realated to aborting the previous Ajax calls , could you please put this property in your config

```
autoAbort : true
```

This will abort the previous ajax calls.
Hopw it helps you.

Comment: I will try this but my question remains unanswered. Why does it say that the request is "PENDING"?